# Java Random Number Array Error

Tags: java, arrays, random

I've written a small Java app to generate arrays randomly, with random numbers. This class works properly:

Dice.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dice {
    private int i = 10;
    private int value = 0;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public void roll_dice() {
        int g = i;

        value = rnd.nextInt(g); // Here is not make a  single error.
        if ((value != 0) & (value <= 6)) {
            System.out.println("Number is :" + value);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Error number should be between 1 and 6. Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to compile this following class, however, I get the following error:

> Error cannot find symbol - method nextInt(int)

Random.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random {
    private int[] number;
    private int g;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public void Bicbig(int amount) {
        g = amount;

        if ((amount >= 1) & (amount <= 100)) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Between 1 and 100. Please try again .");
        }
    }

    public void generate() {
        number = new int[g];

        int u = rnd.nextInt(g); // Error cannot find symbol - method nextInt(int)
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't name your class as `Random`. It hides `java.util.Random`. Program will compile after renaming

Answer (score 1):

You called your class Random, overriding java's Random class.
Rename it.

The nextInt() method doesnt exist in your random class

Answer (score 1):

You have a name clash between your `Random` function, and the one in `java.util`.

1. Remove `import java.util.*;` and refer to the Java library function as `java.util.Random`.
2. Rename your `Random` class.

In reality, I'd do both.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
private Random rnd = new Random() ;
```

to

```
private java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
```